# Dynamic Array of matrix

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm in difficult to resolve this problem:

```
typedef struct {
.....
} info;   
info array[1000][10][10]; //now i have this 3d matrix
```

For memory optimization i want to allocate dynamically the first dimension: i want to have a dynamic array of matrix[10][10]. So i have declare a pointer like this:

```
info *array[10][10];
```

But how to do a malloc do add for example N matrix[10][10] to the array?

I tried:

```
info *array[10][10]=malloc(N*sizeof(array));
```

Comment: Your attempt declares an array of array of pointers. What you want is a pointer to an array of arrays.  `int (*array)[10][10] = malloc(N * sizeof *array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by WhozCraig in the coments and kiranBiradar in his answer, your attempt to allocate:

```
info *array[10][10]=malloc(N*sizeof(array));
```

was an attempt to allocate for an *array or pointer arrays*. You were allocating for `N` `10x10` array of pointers.

What you intended was to allocate storage for `N` `10x10` `info`. To do so, you need to declare `array` as a *pointer to array* `info [10][10]`. Declared in this manner you are then free to allocate for `N 10x10` array `info` in a single allocation (with the benefit of only requiring a single `free` (as opposed to allocating for `info ***` and requiring separate allocations for pointers, row-pointers, and finally elements-per-row). But to declare a *pointer to array* `info [10][10]`, you must declare arrays as:

```
info (*array)[10][10];
```

(note: depending on how you use `array` throughout the code and whether initialization of all elements to some default value is beneficial, you can use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. `calloc` will allocate and zero all bytes (the additional time required to zero the new memory is generally negligible)).

> **And how can i do a realloc of array (in case i need more space)?**

Since you have declared `array` as a *pointer to array* `info[10][10]` and have allocated storage in one shot, you simply need to `realloc` to create a larger block of memory for your storage. There are a number of allocation schemes to efficiently handle reallocation and you have the freedom to handle it however you want.

The rule-of-thumb is to generally declare storage for some reasonably anticipated number of pointers and `10x10` arrays of `info`. You keep a counter for the number of pointers and arrays currently allocated (say in `nptrs`). You keep a second counter of the number you have currently filled (say `ndx` -- short for index). When your index reaches the number of pointers and arrays allocated, you then `realloc` storage for somewhere between `1.5 - 2` times more storage, update your counter for `nptrs` and keep going until `ndx == nptrs` again, and repeat.

A short example may help. Since the members of `info` are undefined, lets just use a simple *pointer to array* `int [10][10]` for the example. The process would be the same for any collection, the only difference being `sizeof *array` would change the number of bytes allocated for each 10x10 array. (if you have additional members of `info` requiring dynamic allocation -- that would be an additional requirement)

When reallocating, *always* assign the return `realloc` to a *temporary* pointer. If `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL` and if you assign that to your original pointer -- you have just created a memory leak and lost the reference to your original block of memory. By using a temporary pointer, if `realloc` fails, your original data, and the pointer to it, remain valid.

A example that simply fills each 10x10 array with a constant number (e.g. `1, 2, 3, ...`) and calls `realloc` twice to increase allocation for the 10x10 blocks from `8` to `16` and finally `32` would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NMTRX  8    /* if you need constants, then #define one (or more) */
#define MSIZE 10    /* don't use "magic numbers" in your code, unless    */
#define NTEST 24    /* mandatory (like scanf field-width modifiers)      */

/** set single MSIZExMSIZE array to n */
void set_m_to_n (int m[MSIZE][MSIZE], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MSIZE; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < MSIZE; j++)
            m[i][j] = n;
}

/** print single MSIZExMSIZE array */
void print_m (int m[MSIZE][MSIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MSIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MSIZE; j++)
            printf (" %2d", m[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

/** realloc to twice 'sz * *nelement' bytes returning
 *  pointer to reallocated block on success, NULL otherwise.
 */
void *realloc_2x (void *ptr, size_t sz, size_t *nelem)
{
    char *memptr = realloc (ptr, 2 * *nelem * sz);
    if (memptr == NULL) {
        perror ("realloc-m");
        return NULL;
    }   /* optionally zero all new memory */
    memset (memptr + *nelem * sz, 0, *nelem * sz);
    *nelem *= 2;  /* update nelem (nptrs) to reflect new allocation */

    return memptr;    /* return pointer to new block for assignment */
}

int main (void) {

    size_t ndx = 0,         /* index */
        nptrs = NMTRX;      /* initial pointers to allocate */
    int (*m)[MSIZE][MSIZE]; /* pointer to MSIZExMSIZE array */

    m = calloc (nptrs, sizeof *m);  /* allocate & initialize zero */
    if (m == NULL) {        /* validate allocation */
        perror ("calloc-m");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (ndx = 0; ndx < NTEST; ndx++) { /* loop filling NTEST arrays */
        if (ndx == nptrs) { /* check if index reached allocation */
            void *tmp = realloc_2x (m, sizeof *m, &nptrs);  /* realloc_2x */
            if (tmp == NULL)/* validate reallocation */
                break;      /* don't exit on failure, original data good */
            m = tmp;        /* assign reallocated block to m */
        }
        set_m_to_n (m[ndx], ndx + 1);   /* set array values to ndx+1 */
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {  /* output all MSIZExMSIZE arrays */
        printf ("\nm[%2zu]:\n", i);
        print_m (m[i]);
    }

    free (m);   /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

The output is simply the pointer and each 10x10 block of numbers:

```
$ ./bin/arr3d_dyn_ptr2d

m[ 0]:
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

m[ 1]:
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2

...
m[23]:
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
```

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/arr3d_dyn_ptr2d
==25240== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25240== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25240== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25240== Command: ./bin/arr3d_dyn_ptr2d
==25240==

m[ 0]:
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

m[ 1]:
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2

...
m[23]:
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
==25240==
==25240== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25240==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25240==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 22,400 bytes allocated
==25240==
==25240== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25240==
==25240== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25240== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
info (*array)[10][10]=malloc(N*sizeof(*array)); //declares pointer to 2d array
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thank You so much. And how can i do a realloc of array (in case i need more space)?

Comment: `array = realloc(array, sizeof(*array)*(N+1));`  @donzPaul

Comment: i tried to do it but it doesn't work. I don't know why

Comment: How are you verifying it?

Comment: doing array = realloc(array, sizeof(*array)*(N+1));                                                        i lost data that exists before realloc. I don't know why but it's a problem maybe not related with the original question.